# Including optional fields in an ORM query

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to execute a dynamic query but three of the fields are dynamic and not required. In SQL Server the query is:

```sql
SELECT 
roles.id,
roles.name,
roles.abbreviation,
roles.active,
(CASE WHEN roles.updated_at IS NULL
    THEN roles.created_at
    ELSE roles.updated_at
    END) as last_Modified,
(CASE WHEN user_roles_count.number_of_users IS NULL
    THEN 0
    ELSE user_roles_count.number_of_users
    END) as number_of_users
FROM roles
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT user_roles.role_id, COUNT(user_roles.user_id) as number_of_users
        FROM user_roles GROUP BY user_roles.role_id
    ) as user_roles_count ON roles.id = user_roles_count.role_id ORDER BY roles.id ASC, last_Modified DESC;
```

The columns name roles.name, roles.active and ORDER BY last_modified are dynamic are not required.

Currently with SQLAlchemy I've done this

```py
def get_roles(session, offset, limit):
    status_1 = f"""(CASE WHEN roles.updated_at IS NULL
        THEN roles.created_at
        ELSE roles.updated_at
        END) as last_Modified"""
    count_Query = session.query(UserRoles.role_id, func.count(
        UserRoles.user_id).label("number_of_users")).group_by(UserRoles.role_id).subquery()
    status_2 = f"""(CASE WHEN {count_Query.c.role_id} IS NULL
    THEN 0
    ELSE {count_Query.c.role_id}
    END) as number_of_users"""
    statement_result = session.query(
        Roles.id,
        Roles.name,
        Roles.abbreviation,
        Roles.active,
        text(status_1),
        text (status_2)
    ).join(count_Query, count_Query.c.role_id == Roles.id,
    isouter=True).order_by(asc(Roles.id)).slice(offset, limit).all()
    columns = ["id", "name", "abbreviation",
                "active", "updatedAt", "numberOfUsers"]
    get_products = struct_response(statement_result, columns)
    return get_products
```

How can I implement the dynamic fields?

**Solution found**
Reviewing the input data I found that my pagination (offset and limit) were wrong so I fixed and the code works as expected. Thanks to all how suggest solutions for this issue and just added the optional fileds verification as singles if in case they are in the event

```
def get_roles(session, offset, limit, event):
status_1 = f"""(CASE WHEN roles.updated_at IS NULL
    THEN roles.created_at
    ELSE roles.updated_at
    END) as last_Modified"""

count_Query = session.query(UserRoles.role_id, func.count(
    UserRoles.user_id).label("number_of_users")).group_by(UserRoles.role_id).subquery()

status_2 = f"""(CASE WHEN {count_Query.c.role_id} IS NULL
THEN 0
ELSE {count_Query.c.role_id}
END) as number_of_users"""

query = session.query(
    Roles.id,
    Roles.name,
    Roles.abbreviation,
    Roles.active,
    text(status_1),
    text(status_2)
).join(count_Query, count_Query.c.role_id == Roles.id,
    isouter=True).order_by(asc(Roles.id))

if "name" in event:
    name = event["name"]
    search = "%{}%".format(name)
    query = query.filter(Roles.name.like(search))
if "status" in event:
    query = query.filter(Roles.active == event["status"])
if "newest_first" in event:
    if event["newest_first"] == True:
        query = query.order_by(asc(Roles.created_at))
    else:
        query = query.order_by(desc(Roles.created_at))

query = query.slice(offset, limit).all()

columns = ["id", "name", "abbreviation",
        "active", "updatedAt", "numberOfUsers"]
get_roles = struct_response(query, columns)

return get_roles
```

Comment: Forgive me, but when you say "dynamic filters" do you really mean "dynamic fields"?

Comment: Yes, that's what I want

Answer (score 1):

You can build a list of the fields you want to include and then pass that *list to the query, e.g.,

```py
from sqlalchemy import Boolean, Column, Integer, select, String
from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()


class Roles(Base):
    __tablename__ = "roles"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(50))
    abbreviation = Column(String(5))
    active = Column(Boolean)


# basic query
columns_to_include = [Roles.id, Roles.abbreviation]
query = select(*columns_to_include)
print(query)
"""
SELECT roles.id, roles.abbreviation 
FROM roles
"""

# add optional field
columns_to_include.append(Roles.name)
query = select(*columns_to_include)
print(query)
"""
SELECT roles.id, roles.abbreviation, roles.name 
FROM roles
"""
```

You can do the same thing with `.order_by()`:

```py
# basic order_by
columns_to_order_by = [Roles.id]
query = select(*columns_to_include).order_by(*columns_to_order_by)
print(query)
"""
SELECT roles.id, roles.abbreviation, roles.name 
FROM roles ORDER BY roles.id
"""

# add another field for select() and order_by()
columns_to_include.append(Roles.active)
columns_to_order_by.append(Roles.active)
query = select(*columns_to_include).order_by(*columns_to_order_by)
print(query)
"""
SELECT roles.id, roles.abbreviation, roles.name, roles.active 
FROM roles ORDER BY roles.id, roles.active
"""
```